# MVVMCross binding - How to change the visibility of object

Tags: android, binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I need to learn how to bind and change the property of elements.

I should change the visibility of element by clicking the button

I have `Hello.axml` with different elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Strings[VerificationPhoneText]" />
<TextView
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Variable01" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Strings[EnterButton]; Click ClickCommand" />
<GestureOverlayView
    android:layout_height="284dp"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(MyProperty)">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_check_circle_black_48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp" />
</GestureOverlayView>
```

I have installed Visibility Plugin:

```
PM> Install-Package MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility -Version 5.6.3
```

And edited my `HelloViewModel.cs`:

```
     using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
     using System.Windows.Input;

namespace My.Project.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HelloViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _myProperty;

        public bool MyProperty
        {
        get
        {
           return _myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
           _myProperty = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
  }

        public ICommand ClickCommand => new MvxCommand(() =>
        {
            MyProperty = !MyProperty;
        });
    }
}
```

But I still have a problem - all elements are visible at the beginning and the button doesn't work.

UPD.
My `HelloView.cs`:

```
using Android.App;

    namespace My.Project.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity]
    public class HelloView:BaseView
    {
        protected override int LayoutResource => Resource.Layout.HelloView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me learn it!

Comment: Visibility is built in bindable property

Comment: @miechooy I use full Xamarin, not Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Yup i am also using MvvmCross with xamarin not xamarin forms

Answer (score 5):

As @c.lamont.dev says Visibility is managed as a plugin (another package) of MvvmCross: `MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility` which you have to add in the PCL and in every platform you want to use it.

Even though what @miechooy works, it can be improved firstly as @c.lamont.dev in the comment by using directly the [Visbiility converters](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters?#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters) provided by the plugin, i.e. `MvxVisibilityValueConverter` and `MvxInvertedVisibilityValueConverter`; they allow us to directly bind to a ViewModel property with that converter and it internally converts the ViewModel property's value to the correct value of `Visibility` in our platform `View`, e.g. in Android it converts from the ViewModel's property value to a `ViewStates`.

It also does a preconversion from whatever type the property is to visibility: so let's say instead of a bool you have an Object like Client, then if you bind with that converter to that property directly it will return `Visible` if the Client is not `null` and `Collapsed` otherwise (it applies to iOS too returning `false` or `true` for the `Hidden` property).

Example of binding:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(MyProperty)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And to change your Visibility by clicking on the button you have to change your property (as @miechooy stated) and command a bit:

```
private bool _myProperty;
public bool MyProperty
{
    get
    {
       return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
       _myProperty = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

public ICommand ClickToToggleMyPropertyVisibilityCommand => new MvxCommand(() =>
{
    MyProperty = !MyProperty;
});
```

---

Now, let's say you want to have you own converter because you have a more complicated logic, then you can inherit from `MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<T>` where you can return a `MvxVisibility` which is the object that `MvvmCross` uses to act as an abstraction of how the platform manage Visibility and therefore it can manage it from the PCL directly, sharing more code between the platforms.

Let's jump to an example: Having a `ViewModel` with a `MyClient` Property of type `Client`:

```
public class Client
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class MyVM : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    private Client _myClient;
    public Client MyClient
    {
       get
       {
           return _myClient;
       }
       set
       {
           _myClient = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyClient);
       }
    }

    ...
}
```

You would like to show in your view only the client if it is active and it's name is not "Admin" so you'd need a custom visibility converter:

```
public class MyOwnVisibilityConverter : MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<Client>
{
    protected override MvxVisibility Convert(Client value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.IsActive && value.Name != "Admin" ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

finally in your View:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility MyOwnVisibility(MyClient)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

HIH

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to implement it. I can't use `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`, so I use `GestureOverlayView`. I have installed Visibility Plugin and edited the code but I still have the same problem - all elements are visible

Comment: you have `MyProperty` as private, it should be public and should raise its property change in the setter so that the View can be notified of MyProperty's change. I've updated my answer with that

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. But it doesn't help. I edited the post again. And for some reason, the button is ahead of this overlay. I.e. I can see the screen, the overlay with text and image  that overlaps the screen, and the button too

Comment: You are using a `RelativeLayout` but you are not positioning your views relative to the other ones, here https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/ it explains how to use it. Btw can you also add the code of you ...View.cs?

Comment: When I have only the screen without overlay I use relative positions. But, in this case, I don't know how can I use it with a simple overlay. It's only the notification for users. Yes, I'll add Views.cs, it's quite standard

Comment: IDK if you mean all the elements of the `RelativeLayout` to be overlapped as in the question. But if not, you have to provide an id for each of them and the do something like `android:layout_below="@id/my_view_on_top_of_this" and for the first one it is not needed because it'll be placed in the top left corner of the `RelativeLayout` but you could also add `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` if you wanted

Comment: Yes, I use IDs too. And something like `android:layout_below="@id/myelement"` And if I use the toolbar for the first element on page I use `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"`. But now I'm really confused by this problem, and nothing helps

Answer (score 2):

As described in comment. MvvmCross already created Visibility binding. There is an example:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility MyProperty, Converter=BooleanToVisibilty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Just declare proeprty in you view model

```
  public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                _myProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And finally craete BooleanToVisiblityConverter:

```
 public class BooleanToVisibiltyValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
    {
        protected override ViewStates Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the Visibility is included in MvvmCross? I think you need to have the MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility package. Then you don't need the converter, you can simply do `local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(MyProperty)`

Comment: Thank you for advice! I can integrate this solution without build errors. But I still don't understand how to change the visibility by the click on the button. I changed the code in the post. In this case, all elements are visible